# GitHub for Desktop AssemblyInfo commit

Tags: github, version, assemblyinfo

In GitHub for Desktop, if any version change commit, eg: AssemblyInfo commit, how there's a small icon showing the version.
see the screenshot [Screenshot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJEGZ.jpg)

I update AssemblyInfo and committed, but it's not showing for me.
Also googled it but I didn't get any result which I'm expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

We just need to add tag, that's it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).